# ./autogen.sh: line 28: Command not found #139

Tags: cygwin

I was trying to use [libqrencode](https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode) on windows, so I had to run autogen.sh at first. I entered into the directory of librencode with CygWin shell. But when I tried to run autogen.sh with the code :

```
sh ./autogen.sh
```

it kept showing that ./autogen.sh: line 28: Command not found.
I got the same result when i tried another method:

```
chmod u+x ./autogen.sh

./autogen.sh
```

The line 28 is

```
autoheader
```

[libqrencode](https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode) is a very popular qr-generating tool, I suppose there should be no problem with his files, that might be something wrong with the way I run it.

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: What's on line 28?

Comment: I open it with text and  can't view the file line by line, the whole content is like this

Comment: Oh, i just open that with Notepad and the line 28 is autoheader

Answer (score 1):

`autoheader` is provided be the cygwin package `autoconf` that is a wrapper for the other
twos autoconf packages.

It will pull some other packages.
I suggest to install also `autoconf-archive` and `automake`

Comment: Thanks! That solved my puzzle. Now I can run my .sh file successfully.